# How to run an app in the background programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this app that I am developing that is connected to a board. If the board detects falls, the app calls a number set by the user. However, the app only works when it is open. I want the app to run in the background so that even if the user is casually browsing through the web or doing something else, if a fall occurs, the app is able to perform the calling function.
Below I have added the piece of code that performs the above said calling function.

@Override

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
public void displayEvent(@AccelerationEvent int event, int data)
    {
        if (mCurrentDetectEvent == FeatureAccelerationEvent.DetectableEvent.FREE_FALL) {
            Context context = getContext();
            mShakeImage.start();
            button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                System.exit(0);
            });

            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Alert")
                        .setMessage("This is an alert")
                        .show();
                //---------------call function from CallScreen()------------------------------------
                Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), CallScreen.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }, 10000);

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need read this
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services
and maybe
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler

You may need to redo your application architecture.

Comment: this does not look like an answer. Don't use *answer* for suggestions. Use comments for that.